# Underscore in if-let

Tags: elisp, elisp-conventions

I often find myself wanting to do something like this:

```lisp
(if-let* ((foo (get-foo))
          (_ (conditionp foo))
          (bar (get-bar-from-foo foo)))
    ...)
```

As an alternative to:

```lisp
(let ((foo (get-foo)))
  (when (and foo (conditionp foo))
    (if-let ((bar (get-bar-from-foo)))
      ...)))
```

The problem is, the underscore is not used so it gives the bytecomp warning: `Warning: variable ‘_’ not left unused`.

I think the first example is much easier to read than the second, is there something similar to the first example which gets around this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Emacs 26, the underscore (or any variable symbol in general) can be omitted:

```
if-let is a Lisp macro in `subr-x.el'.

(if-let SPEC THEN &rest ELSE)

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 25.1.

Bind variables according to SPEC and evaluate THEN or ELSE.
Evaluate each binding in turn, as in `let*', stopping if a
binding value is nil.  If all are non-nil return the value of
THEN, otherwise the last form in ELSE.

Each element of SPEC is a list (SYMBOL VALUEFORM) that binds
SYMBOL to the value of VALUEFORM.  An element can additionally be
of the form (VALUEFORM), which is evaluated and checked for nil;
i.e. SYMBOL can be omitted if only the test result is of             <======
interest.  It can also be of the form SYMBOL, then the binding of
SYMBOL is checked for nil.
```

So your example can be written as:

```el
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'subr-x))

(if-let* ((foo (get-foo))
          ((conditionp foo))
          (bar (get-bar-from-foo foo)))
    ...)
```

Comment: That's really nice, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for not helpfully answering the question posed, but hoping this might help anyway...

Instead of something *"similar to the first"*, I'd likely use something that (I think) is simpler than either of them.

Your first example macro-"expands" to code that I think is clearer, than either of your examples:

```lisp
(macroexpand '(if-let* ((foo (get-foo))
                        (_ (conditionp foo))
                        (bar (get-bar-from-foo foo)))
                  X))
```

gives:

```lisp
(let* ((foo  (and t    (get-foo)))
       (_    (and foo  (conditionp foo)))
       (bar  (and _    (get-bar-from-foo foo))))
  (if bar X))
```

If I were to code that expansion by hand it would be simpler still:

```lisp
(let* ((foo  (get-foo))
       (_    (and foo  (conditionp foo)))
       (bar  (and _    (get-bar-from-foo foo))))
  (if bar X))
```

And that assumes that the sexps would in reality be more complex. Otherwise I'd probably just use something like this:

```lisp
(let ((foo (get-foo)))
  (and foo (conditionp foo) (get-bar-from-foo foo) X))
```

Even just a structural comparison of that with the `if-let*` form shown in @Basil's answer shows that the above sexp is simpler.  Remove everything except the parens from each, to compare:

```lisp
(((())(())(())))  ; Simplified `if-let*` form (@Basil's answer)
(((()))(()()))    ; Simple `let` shown above
```

Comment: > Assuming you meant to put another ) after (_ (conditionp foo)

yep sorry (:
I've accepted Basil's answer but I think I will end up doing one of the suggestions here for Emacs 25 compat, thanks

Comment: I the two aren't equivalent if `X` evaluates `bar` anywhere.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Yes, of course. Along with 8 million other possibilities. ;-)